# LDAP Query to get all OUs a given user has delegated rights to

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to get the following sub OUs from a given OU in an AD via LDAP:

> Get all OUs that can be managed (permission to set passwords, to edit
>   users or groups or whatever) by the given user X.

To get OUs I can filter by `(objectClass=organizationalUnit)`, but how do I filter by management rights, is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.  The management rights are stored in the DACL in the [`nTSecurityDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute.  In order to perform access checks, you have to evaluate every ACE in the DACL because deny trumps allow.  You also have to know every group that the user is a member of, which requires its own query to the [`tokenGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute (or a logon token).  I don't see how you could construct an LDAP query with the [limited operators available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that takes all of the complexities of ACL's into account.